# Unable to set_fact variable based on condition in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements

`MYUSER` should be assigned value `wsadm` or `user1` based on the output of `{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}`
I tried the below however, I'm getting error when I run.

My playbook looks like below:

```yaml
---
- name: "Play 1-Find the details here"

  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
 
   - name: "Search for {{ Number }} in the database"
     command: >
       mysql --user=root --password=mypass deployment
       --host=localhost  -Ns -e "SELECT dest_ip,layer FROM deploy_dets WHERE num LIKE '{{ Number }}'"
     register: command_result

   - set_fact:
   
       dest_ip: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[0] }}"
       MYUSER: "wsadm"
     when: {{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }} == 'WAS'
       MYUSER: "user1"
     when: {{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }} == 'APP'

   - name: "Print output for Number Search"
     debug:
       msg: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}"
       msg: "{{ MYUSER }}"
```

Error Output:

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available.
> Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all' ERROR! Syntax
> Error while loading YAML.   did not find expected key The error
> appears to be in
> '/app/axmw/Ansible/playbook/finacle_deployment/assignvars.yml': line
> 22, column 57, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem. The offending line appears to be:
> MYUSER: "wsadm"
> when: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}" == 'WAS'
> ^ here We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
> missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
> start a value.

I also tried the below but they too did not help:

First:

```yaml
   MYUSER: "wsadm"
 when: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}" == 'WAS'
   MYUSER: "user1"
 when: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}" == 'APP'
```

Second:

```yaml
   MYUSER: "wsadm"
 when: command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] == 'WAS'
   MYUSER: "user1"
 when: command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] == 'APP'
```

Third:

```yaml
   layer: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}"
   MYUSER: "wsadm"
 when: layer == 'WAS'
   MYUSER: "user1"
 when: layer == 'APP'
```

I'm on the latest version of ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
when: "command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] == 'APP'"
```

Make sure `command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1]` gives you what you realy want

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error related to inventory file, as seen in the below error.

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available.
> Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all' ERROR! Syntax
> Error while loading YAML

Also, you have syntax error in your ansible playbook, as evident from this error.

> The offending line appears to be: MYUSER: "wsadm" when: "{{
> command_result.stdout.split('\t')[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816494/16958560) }}" == 'WAS' ^

First thing I want to bring into your notice is that we should avoid using jinja2 templating in `when condition`.

I have written a small playbook for you which takes a variable and splits it on the basis of `\t` and suits your use case.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - user: "user:  WAS"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ user }}"

    - set_fact:
        MYUSER: "wsadm"
        when: user.split('\t')[1] == "WAS"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ MYUSER }}"
```

**Output**

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "user:\tWAS"
}
Saturday 07 September 2019  06:57:29 +0000 (0:00:00.081)       0:00:00.218 **** 

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
Saturday 07 September 2019  06:57:29 +0000 (0:00:00.064)       0:00:00.283 **** 

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "wsadm"
}
```

And also keep in mind to first check if you are getting the right value or not in the variable which you are trying to split as [suggested by @Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57816494/16958560)